# JSTL foreach loop generates too many empty lines (blank HTML space)

Tags: html, jsp, foreach, jstl

I am generating `HTML5` page menu items in `JSP` by reading data from the list that is in `ServletContext` (using `JSTL foreach` loop). And this way I am creating content of the `<nav> HTML5` tag.

This works fine, I am getting page look I want. But, when I look at the `HTML` page source (generated from JSP), there are too many empty lines (blank space), generated in `foreach` loop.

This the code that generates this content:

```
<li><a href="#">Categories</a>
    <ul class="droprightMenu">
        <li><a href="#">All</a>
            <ul class="droprightMenu">

                <!-- first list iteration, top level categories, level1  -->
                <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel1">

                    <c:if test="${catLevel1.getParentCategory()==null }">
                        <li><a href="#">${catLevel1.getName() }</a> <!-- second list iteration, level 2 categories, 
                                     parentCategory is level1  -->
                            <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel2">

                                    <c:if
                                        test="${catLevel2.getParentCategory().getId()==catLevel1.getId() }">
                                        <li><a href="#">${catLevel2.getName() }</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                      parentCategory is level2  -->
                                            <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                                <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel3">

                                                    <c:if
                                                        test="${catLevel3.getParentCategory().getId()==catLevel2.getId() }">
                                                        <li><a href="#">${catLevel3.getName() }</a></li>
                                                    </c:if>

                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </ul></li>
                                    </c:if>

                                </c:forEach>
                            </ul></li>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>

            </ul></li>
    </ul></li>
```

and the generated content looks something like this:

```
    <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
        <ul class="droprightMenu">
            <li><a href="#">All</a>
                <ul class="droprightMenu">

                    <!-- first list iteration, top level categories, level1  -->



                            <li><a href="#">Sports</a> <!-- second list iteration, level 2 categories, 
                                         parentCategory is level1  -->
                                <ul class="droprightMenu">















                                            <li><a href="#">Football</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                      parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>





                                            <li><a href="#">Basketball</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                      parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>





                                            <li><a href="#">Hockey</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                      parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>



























                                </ul></li>




                            <li><a href="#">Politics</a> <!-- second list iteration, level 2 categories, 
                                         parentCategory is level1  -->
                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                </ul></li>




                            <li><a href="#">IT</a> <!-- second list iteration, level 2 categories, 
                                         parentCategory is level1  -->
                                <ul class="droprightMenu">



























                                            <li><a href="#">Software</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                          parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>





                                            <li><a href="#">Hardware</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                          parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>





                                            <li><a href="#">Programming</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                          parentCategory is level2  -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">











































                                                            <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>





                                                            <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>



                                                </ul></li>





                                            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a> <!-- third list iteration, level3 categories
                                                          parentCategory is level2 -->
                                                <ul class="droprightMenu">

















































                                                </ul></li>











                                </ul></li>






























                </ul></li>
        </ul></li>
```

How to prevent generating these empty lines? So that page source markup looks normal.

Comment: Why? would you be maintaining the page source?

Comment: @unekwu Well, its really no big deal. But, when I view page source it looks so streched. So, just asking is there a way to render/shrink this page, to remove those unnesesarry empty lines?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jstl but I'll use 'c:out' to render the objects (you could create a template and do an include if it gets messy). I don't know that it will solve the problem though.

Comment: adding `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` in the JSP page, blank lines are removed